# Download only visible content

Tags: android, lazy-loading, scrollview

I'm writing android app which uses lazy load pattern. I need to download content of view if user scrolled to it. Is there any way?

Comment: I tried to set onFocusListener to my views, but it seems like view can be focused being not viewed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, see this [talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

what you are looking for is called holder pattern.

refer [here](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) for code

almost all android apps with dynamic listView content use this pattern in one form or other,

it can be easily modified for your particular case.

Comment: It's ok, but actually I have to use my custom views

Comment: when you asked lazy-load I immediately thought about listviews, in custom views you can query bounds to check if it falls in the phone bounds, it requires a lot of code but certainly works like a charm.

Comment: as I said lot of custom code, however why would you want to handle scrolling?